# gnu.mail.providers.nntp newsrc

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, gnu, nntp, usenet

Referencing the API docs for [gnu.mail.providers.nntp](http://www.gnu.org/software/classpathx/javamail/javadoc/gnu/mail/providers/nntp/package-summary.html), I'm trying to generate a list of folders on localhost nntp where I run [leafnode](http://leafnode.sourceforge.net/).

However, it seems that ${user.home}/.newsrc isn't loading correctly because I'm getting a zero length array with:

```
store = session.getStore(new URLName(props.getProperty("nntp.host")));
store.connect();
root = store.getDefaultFolder();
Folder[] f = root.list();
LOG.warning("folders array " + f.length);
```

How can I debug whether the newsrc is loading correctly for the store?

properties file:

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=589
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.imap.host=imap.gmail.com
mail.imap.port=993
mail.imap.connectiontimeout=5000
mail.imap.timeout=5000
mail.user=hawat.thufir@gmail.com
nntp.group=gwene.com.economist
nntp.host=nntp://localhost/
mail.nntp.newsrc.file=/home/thufir/.newsrc
jdbc.user=java
jdbc.password=password
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nntp?autoReconnect=true
jdbc.jndiName=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nntp?autoReconnect=true
```

Incidentally, the connection to the store is fine for the group specified in the properties file.

setting debug to true gives:

```
May 05, 2012 2:22:33 AM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.model.PropertiesReader getProps
INFO: NNTP.loadMessages...
DEBUG: nntp: newsrc loading /home/thufir/.newsrc
DEBUG: nntp: newsrc load: 0 groups in 1ms
May 05, 2012 2:22:35 AM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.controller.Usenet connect
WARNING: folders array 0
May 05, 2012 2:22:35 AM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.controller.Usenet loadFoldersList
WARNING: folders 0
May 05, 2012 2:22:35 AM net.bounceme.dur.nntp.controller.MessagesEnum <init>
INFO: starting controller..
```

So it looks like the newsrc is loading, but has 0 groups.  Yet the newsrc in question is like so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat .newsrc
gwene.com.economist 1-1000000
thufir@dur:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malformed newsrc, fixed to:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat .newsrc
gwene.com.economist: 1-100
thufir@dur:~$
```

works fine.